# no HASH key value present - AWS DynamoDBMapper.batchLoad

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I am attempting to batch load a couple items in AWS' Java SDK and I keep getting the error that no HASH key value is present, even though I set the correct primary key for each of the values.  Here is my code, the crash occurs when I hit the `dbMapper.batchLoad()` line.

ArrayList friendsTblsToGet = new ArrayList();

```
    Friends friendTblOne = new Friends();
    friendTblOne.setFriendsId(friendsTblInfo.get("friendId1"));
    Friends friendTblTwo = new Friends();
    friendTblTwo.setFriendsId(friendsTblInfo.get("friendTbl2"));

    friendsTblsToGet.add(friendTblOne);
    friendsTblsToGet.add(friendTblTwo);

    Map<String, List<Object>> friendsToLoad = dbMapper.batchLoad(friendsTblsToGet);
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Friends[friendsId]; no HASH key value present",
  "errorType": "com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel.convertKey(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:329)",
    "com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel.convertKey(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:310)",
    "com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.batchLoad(DynamoDBMapper.java:1282)",
    "com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AbstractDynamoDBMapper.batchLoad(AbstractDynamoDBMapper.java:196)",
    "com.treyherman.lambda.gifwrap.InteractionInterface.getFriendsTables(InteractionInterface.java:230)",
    "com.treyherman.lambda.gifwrap.UserInteractionFunctionHandler.getFriendsTables(UserInteractionFunctionHandler.java:64)",
    "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
    "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)",
    "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)",
    "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"
  ]
```

Does anyone know where I could be going wrong with this?  I followed the AWS documentation for it, found here: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Methods.html#w1ab1c13c19c21c43c31

Comment: Can you share the code of the `Friends` class?

Comment: Also, what is `friendsTblInfo`?

Comment: Have you annotated the hash key with @DynamoDBHashKey. Example @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "friendsId")
 public Integer getFriendsId() {
  return friendsId;
 }

Comment: friendsTblInfo is just the Map<String, String> value. And yes it is annotated with the @DynamoDBHashKey

Comment: @hermt2 were u able to find a root cause of this problem. I am getting same error and i have no clue what causing this.